# Machine epsilon, ε: What is step to next smaller value from 1?

Tags: floating-point, numerical

We know that machine epsilon, ε, is ”the difference between 1 and the least value greater than 1 that is representable in the given floating point type”.<sup>1</sup>

However, the definition says nothing about the next smaller value. What is the difference between 1 and the next smaller value?

---

Note

<sup>1</sup> ISO/IEC C 2011 standard, section 5.2.4.2.2, paragraph 13 (not authoritative on floating point but one example of the common description of machine epsilon).

Comment: No, machine epsilon is not defined as “the smallest positive number st (1+ε)>1”. That definition defines a different number from what is intended, which is “the difference between the successor of 1 and 1”: http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/05/09/FLT_EPSILON

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

1-ε/2 is the largest number below 1.  1+ε is the smallest number above 1.

The significand for a normalized floating-point number is always in the range [1,2).  Therefore, to represent numbers in the range [0.5,1), the exponent is -1 and the LSB is half as large.

So in binary, 1 + ε is something like:

> 1 + ε = 1.000...0001 ⨯ 2<sup>0</sup>

You can see that there's no number between 1 and 1 + ε, which matches the definition for ε.

But 1 - ε is something like:

> 1 - ε = 1.111...1110 ⨯ 2<sup>-1</sup>

So there is exactly one number between 1 - ε and 1, that is, 1 - ε/2.

Comment: How about `(1-ε/3)` isn't that larger than `(1-ε/2)` ?

Comment: Would you mind to point me to a reading about them, please?
I want to get an idea of why this is the case.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd: 1-ε/3 = 1-ε/2, they are same floating point number.

Comment: So (1-ε)<1 does hold.
But  (1-ε/2)==1 does NOT hold since  (1-ε/2) is smaller than 1?

Comment: @Sean: Right, 1-ε/2<1.

Comment: Example in Python: `>>> 1.0 - sys.float_info.epsilon / 2
0.9999999999999999
    >>> (1.0 - sys.float_info.epsilon / 2) == (1.0 -sys.float_info.epsilon / 3)
    True` EDIT: bah, formatting.